# Вывести отсортированный список с помощью метода _.sortBy by underscore.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

В проекте использованы backbone + underscore и jade + stylus.

В шаблоне jade имеется переменная, которая выводит не сортированный список

```
<% _.each(territory_list, function(territory) {%>
```

Для вывода списка используется метод `_.each`.

Если я правильно понимаю, чтобы вывести отсортированный список, необходимо использовать метод `_.sortBy` для выводимого списка `territory_list`. Но не понимаю где этот метод применить. Представляю что запись должна быть примерно такая (не работает):

```
<% _.each_.sortBy(territory_list, function(territory) {%>
```

Как вывести отсортированный список с использованием метода от underscore?

**UPD**

Уточняю вопрос. В результате сортировки должен вывестись список по возрастающей. Например:

```
Территория 1
Территория 2
Территория 3
...
Территория 20
```

и т.д.

Comment: `_.sortBy` предполагает сортировку по _какому-либо параметру_ (либо с использованием функции-итератора). Отсюда вопрос: что представляют из себя элементы `territory_list` и какова логика их сортировки.

Comment: `territory_list` это - как я написала в вопросе - список, т.е. `<ul><li></li></ul>`...

Comment: И как вы его хотите сортировать? Это же уже html, так?

Comment: сортировать по возрастающей, т.е. от 1 до 20 и т.д., там текст и номер, например: `Территория 1`

Comment: Еще раз: если элементы `territory_list` - это строки с html, то никаких `1` и  `20` уже нет.

Comment: Добавьте все вот это в вопрос: с четким примером, что есть `territory_list` и что вы хотите получить на выходе. Иначе разговор ни о чем

Comment: Ну и я более чем уверен, что `_.sortBy` вам не нужен. Но это станет ясно наверняка, только после уточнения вопроса

Comment: Вы все равно не указали, что есть `territory_list`. Это массив строк или что-то еще?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не знаю, откуда взялись ваши представления, но они абсолютно не верны (достаточно мельком просмотреть [документацию Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) чтобы в этом убедиться).

Более того, метод [`_.sortBy`](http://underscorejs.org/#sortBy) нужен не для сортировки массивов строк, а для сортировки *коллекций* (массивов однотипных объектов). Для сортировки массива строк намного лучше подходит метод [`Array.prototype.sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort). Но тут есть одна тонкость: этот метод использует [*лексикографический порядок*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA) строк при сортировке. То есть, вы получите:

```
Foo 1
Foo 10
Foo 2
```

вместо

```
Foo 1
Foo 2
Foo 10
```

Чтобы получить правильный результат, вам нужно использовать *натуральную* сортировку вместо лексикографической. В общем виде, задача требует отдельного рассмотрения и может потребовать использования сторонних библиотек (например, [javascript-natural-sort](https://www.npmjs.com/package/javascript-natural-sort), но Google расскажет вам и о других, которые могут быть лучше/удобнее).

Если же все действительно так просто, как вы говорите в вопросе (сочетание слова "*Территория*" и целочисленного ее номера), то вам всего лишь надо передать правильную функцию-компаратор методу [`Array.prototype.sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort):

```
var territoryComparator = function(a, b) {
    var numRegExp = /(.*?)(\d+)$/;

    return parseInt(a.replace(numRegExp, '$2'))
        - parseInt(b.replace(numRegExp, '$2'))
};
```

При этом, ваш шаблон должен иметь вид:

```
<% _.each(territory_list.sort(territoryComparator), function(territory) { %>
    <!-- А здесь вы можете отрисовывать ваши "территории" -->
<% }) %>
```